# Laravel - created command not working on shared hosting

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, shared-hosting, laravel-artisan

I have my Laravel project deployed on shared hosting, and I made a command that delete some old images, command is `php artisan delete:photos`, and on my localhost it is working just fine, but on my shared hosting terminal when I type `php artisan delete:photos` it is not working.
I don't know why, I tried with `php artisan key:generate` but it is not working too.

Any solutions for this?

Comment: "Not working" is not a sufficiently detailed technical explanation of what's going wrong. Do you get errors? Do you get any output whatsoever? Please include this in your question so we know where to begin.

Comment: It is not showing any errors, it's like it deleted photos but when I check my storage on server file manager photos are still there

Comment: @Milos Bro are you able to perform any php artisan command ? If yes then enable the cron in the cpanel of shared hosting

Comment: @KhalidKhan I'm able to preform standard php artisan commands of Laravel, but I can't run any commands that I made, like this one for photos. I also ADD Cron Job and nothing happens